# How to encrypt a file or a folder on f2fs?

Tags: encryption, f2fs

`f2fs` supports per-file encryption, however I can't find any resources about it.

- I know about `eCryptFS`, `LUKS` and `encfs`, that's not the same.

Comment: I can't find anything on this either. I'd like to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`f2fs-tools` includes, [as of `v.1.9`](https://kernel.googlesource.com/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/jaegeuk/f2fs-tools/+/v1.9.0), a tool for encryption management in the `f2fs` filesystem:

`f2fscrypt`

The manual page includes an example that shows how to encrypt a directory (along with instructions on how to setup a `f2fs` filesytem that supports encryption).

---

The only alternative to `f2fscrypt` that I know of is [`fscryptctl`](https://github.com/google/fscryptctl) (I only tried it once and it was on a `ext4` filesystem but according to the author it should work equally well on `f2fs`).

Answer (score 0):

When enabling support to the filesystem in the Linux kernel, it is wise to enable at least the first four options in order to support extended filesystem attributes:

- CONFIG_F2FS_FS
- F2FS_FS_XATTR
- CONFIG_F2FS_FS_POSIX_ACL
- CONFIG_F2FS_FS_SECURITY

**Enabling basic f2fs filesystem options**

```
File systems  --->
   <*> F2FS filesystem support
   [*]   F2FS extended attributes
   [*]     F2FS Access Control Lists
   [*]     F2FS Security Labels
   [*]   F2FS consistency checking feature
   [*]   F2FS Encryption
```

Install the user space tools for the f2fs filesystem:

```
root #emerge --ask sys-fs/f2fs-tools
```

After emerging the userspace tools, create a filesystem by running the mkfs.f2fs command followed by the appropriate device and partition number:

```
root #mkfs.f2fs /dev/sdd1
```

Now at this point, afiak, we can do something like this: http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-security-4/how-to-use-f2fs-encryption-4175581121/ or this: http://blog.quarkslab.com/a-glimpse-of-ext4-filesystem-level-encryption.html. Will they play nice with trim? I'm not sure. I've been trying to get to the bottom of this for a while now and this is the best I can come up with.

Comment: The question here is how to encrypt using `f2fs` per-file encryption (without using `ecryptfs` as in your first link... I'm not going to comment on your second link for obvious reasons...)